# How to parse German Umlaute and other special characters from emails

Tags: python, email, parsing, encoding, character-encoding

I am trying to parse an email using python's `email`-module with its `Parser()` provided by the `email.utils`-submodule.

However, there are some special characters which I was not able to parse / convert correctly.

Here is the script I got so far:

```
import sys
import email
from email.parser import Parser

full_msg = Parser().parse(sys.stdin)
msg = full_msg  # this ugly line is part of former debugging

sender = msg['from']
to = msg['to']
subject = msg['subject']
body = msg.get_payload()
date = msg['Date']


fname = '{}.txt'.format(date)
with open(fname, 'w') as f:
    f.write('{:10}{}\n'.format('Von:', sender))
    f.write('{:10}{}\n'.format('An:', to))
    f.write('{:10}{}\n'.format('Betreff:', subject))
    f.write('{}\n'.format(body))
```

Since I am parsing both international as well as German mails I have to deal with the so called 'Umlaute' (`ä`, `ü`, `ö`) and some other characters like `ß` and the ellipsis (`...`).

So for example a body like

```
Würde Dürfte Könnte
```

get's

```
W=C3=BCrde D=C3=BCrfte K=C3=B6nnte=
```

and a subject of

```
Das dürfte jetzt klappen
```

becomes

```
=?utf-8?Q?Das_d=C3=BCrfte_jetzt_klappen?=
```

Is there a way to deal with those encoding/decoding issues? What am I missing?

---

*UPDATE 1:*

The system's language resp. encoding was set to `en_US.UTF-8`. I changed that to `de_DE.UTF-8` by reconfiguring the available locales. However, this did not change the output at all. `locale` gives:

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

*UPDATE 2:*

I found out that this type of string formatting is called [Quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable). There is a Python module called [quopri](https://docs.python.org/3/library/quopri.html) to handle this format, but I was unable to get satisfying results. However, I switched to JavaScript using [MailParser](https://github.com/andris9/mailparser) which works like a charm.

Comment: Where are you getting the decoded values that you show in your post?  Is that just a raw `cat` of the file, or are you displaying the file with some program?

Comment: That's a `cat` output of the generated txt-file.

Comment: What encoding is your terminal session set to?

Comment: Sorry, but how can I find out?

Comment: It's a setting in your terminal application somewhere.  In PuTTy, for example, it's Settings -> Window -> Translation -> Remote Character Set.

Comment: The command line (Debian shell) told me that this was set to `en_US.UTF-8`. However, changing the locale to `de_DE.UTF-8` (reconfigured all locales for that) does not change the output at all.

Comment: I'm not sure changing the locale environment setting is enough.

Comment: If so, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: There's probably a character encoding setting somewhere in the terminal program, but I don't use Debian so I don't know where to find it.

Comment: The `locale` language settings don't affect how Python interprets an email message; they just control how internationalized software presents to you (i.e. its user interface messages will be in German if it has been localized for German).

Answer (score 1):

*edit*: see the comment from @triplee for a better way to solve this.

---

I guess I'm a bit late to the party...

I had your exact same problem today which lead me to your question. Your second update regarding the quopri library was quite helpful and based on that I found the solution:

```
quopri.decodestring(s).decode("utf-8")
```

with `s` being a string containing quoted printables.

```
>>> import quopri
>>> print(quopri.decodestring('W=C3=BCrde D=C3=BCrfte K=C3=B6nnte=').decode('utf-8'))
Würde Dürfte Könnte
```

Unfortunately this doesn't solve the `=?utf-8?Q?` prefix in your second example:

```
>>> print(quopri.decodestring('=?utf-8?Q?Das_d=C3=BCrfte_jetzt_klappen?=').decode('utf-8'))
=?utf-8?Q?Das_dürfte_jetzt_klappen?
```

Comment: Switching to the modern Python 3.6+ `EmailMessage`API solves many such problems simply by presenting a better interface. Perhaps throw away what you have and start over with the [examples from the `email` documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Comment: You need a specific RFC2047 decoder for the Subject (it's not just quoted-printable); there is one in `email.utilities` (IIRC) but as commented above, just using the modern API avoids these complications by and large. I posted a separate answer to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1):

The older `email` interface from Python 3.2 was pretty clunky and forced you to learn a lot about the underlying MIME structure. Simply switching to the modern API will relieve you of (most of) that burden.

Here is a refactoring to use modern Python to solve this.

```
import sys  
# import email  # commented out - you never used this
from email import message_from_binary_file
from email.policy import default


# The .buffer is to read bytes instead of characters
# policy=default selects the modern EmailMessage API
msg = message_from_binary_file(sys.stdin.buffer, policy=default)
# msg = full_msg  # redundant

sender = msg['from']
to = msg['to']
subject = msg['subject']
body = msg.get_payload(decode=True)
date = msg['Date']

sys.stdout.write('{:10}{}\n'.format('Von:', sender))
sys.stdout.write('{:10}{}\n'.format('An:', to))
sys.stdout.write('{:10}{}\n'.format('Betreff:', subject))
sys.stdout.write('{}\n'.format(body))
```

When run on a sample message like this one;

```
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Das_d=C3=BCrfte_jetzt_klappen?=
Date: Mon, 06 Nov 2023 16:37:18 +0200
From: =?utf-8?b?w7/DtsO8wq4gxpLCrsSxw6lu4oiC?= <your.friend@example.com>
To: =?utf-8?b?ypzDqeKFrOKFvNC+IOKFvsSbw6XKgMSb0ZXhjqI=?= <dearest@example.net>
Content-type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-transfer-encoding: base64

anVzdCBhIGJyaWVmIGRlbW8K
```

... produces this output:

```
Von:      ÿöü® ƒ®ıén∂ <your.friend@example.com>
An:       ʜéⅬⅼо ⅾěåʀěѕᎢ <dearest@example.net>
Betreff:  Das dürfte jetzt klappen
b'just a brief demo\n'
```

It's probably less than ideal to read the message from standard input, but as demonstrated above, it can certainly be done.